# Cross-platform online mind mapping tool?

Tags: android, linux, cross-platform

Specifically, one that works on both Linux and Android. But I might need to install it on other devices later on, so the more platforms, the better.

Also, I need it to synchronize between different devices, so that I can edit mind maps on the go.

Also also, what kind of features naturally synergize with mind mapping, that I should be looking for in this app?

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend [Draw.io](https://www.draw.io/), it's a web-based application and you can sync to Dropbox, OneDrive, or export projects and save them anywhere.

It has templates to get you started or to use as examples and is great for mind-mapping, flowcharts, UML diagrams, etc.

You can export them as HTML, PDF, XML, PNG, JPG, and a few more formats.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Draw.io which I believe is excellent, I would also recommend [Miro](https://miro.com/). The one problem I've found with Draw.io is that it can be a bit tedious when you want to do something in a quick and dirty way (which is often the case with mind-mapping - you don't want to focus on the tool's peculiarities but rather on your thoughts).

Disclaimer: Maybe the situation is different now, as I haven't used Draw.io in a while. They even have a desktop app now.